# compile error with open62541 (OPC UA), lwip and freeRTOS on STM32H7

Tags: gcc, stm32, freertos, opc-ua, open62541

I have working system with lwip and freeRTOS on this bord. I would like to add open62541 implementation of OPC UA with single .c and .h files like described [here](https://open62541.org/doc/1.0/building.html#freertos-lwip).

I was able to create open62541 .c and .h files and added these files to my working project. But now I can't compile with gcc for ARM. 
My compiler returns the following partial error message:

> `../Application/CM7/Src/open62541.c:40310:26: error: 'UA_Server {aka struct UA_Server}' has no member named 'serviceMutex'`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

I needed to add the `UA_ARCHITECTURE_FREERTOSLWIP` symbol/define to eclipse.